# ngFor to iterate json sub array with unknown keys

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I get a specific user from my dummy json file and looks like this:

```
"id": "2",
"name": "Marios Manolakeris",
"skills": [
     {
         "skill_1": "Machine Learning",
         "skill_2": "AI",
         "skill_3": "C++"
     }
]
```

I need to iterate through skills, even if theoretically i don't know the key values skill_1, skill_2, skill_3.

So, a solution is to do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of user.skills">{{skill.skill_1}}, {{skill.skill_2}}, {{skill.skill_3}}</div>
```

but, I want to iterate through user.skills automatically.

Is there any way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` when keys are unknown like below:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills">
  <div *ngFor="let item of skill | keyvalue">
        {{item.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

OR 6.1+ onwards you can use `keyvaluepipe` as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills">
  <div *ngFor="let item of objectKeys(skill)">
        {{skill[item]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In .ts

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
public user={"id": "2",
    "name": "Marios Manolakeris",
    "skills": [
        {
            "skill_1": "Machine Learning",
            "skill_2": "AI",
            "skill_3": "C++"
        }
    ]
}
skills:any;
constructor(){
  this.skills = this.user.skills;
}
```

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fst8lm-bjg5hu

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am getting this error though Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Comment: Didn't notice `skills` is an array. Updated my answer.