# How to show nested json data using ngFor in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I tried with few techniques but still I can't figure out it so what is the best way to show this data using angular `*ngFor` loop

```
  "data": {
    "live": [
      {
        "name": "First",
        "image": "XXXX",
        "description": "Blockchain Technology",
        "timezone": "UTC+0"
      },
      {
        "name": "First",
        "image": "XXXX",
        "description": "Blockchain Technology",
        "timezone": "UTC+0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngFor to iterate json sub array with unknown keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462077/ngfor-to-iterate-json-sub-array-with-unknown-keys)

Comment: Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462137/4868839

Comment: you  can try `<div *ngFor="let h of data.live">{{h.name}}</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do not need nested ngFor, you could just use it as follows,

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let myObj of myData.data.live">
      {{ myObj.description }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4opr4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

try with this Hope it will help you.
In your component.ts file access the data from your JSON file like below.

```
yourdata: any = [];

this.httpService.get('./assets/yourjsonfile.json').subscribe(
       data => {
          this.yourdata = data as string [];
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
```

then in your component.html file try to access the content of the yourdata variable which we declared in the component.ts file as follows.

```
<div *ngFor="let Data of yourdata>
   {{ Data.data.live.name}}
   {{ Data.data.live.image}}
   {{ Data.data.live.description}}
   {{ Data.data.live.timezone}}
</div>
```

it will print your JSON data on your UI application.